# How long can a human body function at safe levels in slightly higher and lower gravity?

Tags: biology, gravity

I have a number of alien species from different planets with gravity between 0.5g and 1.75g and I wanted to have groups of each of the species to exist together in a space habitat. As pointed out to me in a previous question, having multiple levels in a rotating habitat would be a way to go as it shouldn't be too much trouble to visit other levels.

I was wondering for how long these species could interact with other species on different levels and how often they could do this? would they need recovery and re adjustment time which would limit how frequently and for how long they can visit certain levels.

Using the human body as an example, for how long and to what increase or decrease in gravity can a human bodies internal systems still function at safe levels?

Comment: There have been a lot of questions on this sort of topic already, for example https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/70892/gravity-difference-and-its-impact-on-humans and https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/158/would-the-human-body-support-living-on-planets-with-a-greater-gravity-than-earth.  Suggest you search existing questions with the same tags you have used.

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 I have searched questions in the past and havent found exactly what I am after. because a half an hour visit a day is acceptable its more about the little and often visits that long trips.

Comment: This breaks down into 3 basic cases:  Case 1 is humans in low to zero gravity - existing answers cover this.  Case 2 is humans in high gravity - there's no data except about humans in acceleration couches or sitting in centrifuges for short periods, as per existing answers.  Case 3 is about the effect of varying amounts of gravity on completely undefined alien species - without information about each of these species no good answer can be written.

Comment: At those levels, probably for a normal lifespan.  Higher gravity is not that much different from an overweight person, or carrying a fairly heavy backpack.  0.5g should be much easier to tolerate than zero g.

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 That is how I went about researching it, but the answers have contradicting views, that Is why I wanted to bring it up again but more specific to my needs. Thats why I said to use humans as an example to make the question answerable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try to predict, how humans will live with higher/lower gravity.

Soviet Union cosmonaut [Valeriy Polyakov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valeri_Polyakov) had spend 437 days and 18 hours aboard Soviet Union Space station [Mir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_station) with zero gravity. He totally spend more than 600 days in space with zero gravity. He is still alive. So, lower gravity seems to be not so fatal. Its worth notice, that 'Mir' station had a lot of physical training apparatus to keep cosmonauts healthy.

For slightly higher gravity - there should be much more pressure on blood system - so, human will have lesser endurance, and higher risks of heard attacks and [thrombs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrombus) - because heart will have to pump little heavier blood, and spend more energy on it. But, if you spend more time laying on back, your heart will rest.

For slighter lower gravity - there should be issues with digestive  and  [Lymphatic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lymphatic_system) systems  - they evolved to work in 1G environment.

But, on same time, humans are very adaptable. Compare [Chuchki people](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chukchi_people), who lives in on shores of North Polar Sea, and [Bedouins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bedouin) from Sahara, they are same humans, but they live in very different conditions.
I think during few generations humans can adapt to either higher or lower gravity.

So, there should be more muscular and short **dwarf like humans who prefer higher gravity**, and more **slim and slender humans who prefer lower gravity**, and they will be able to have nearly normal humans lifespan, if they live in environment, they adapted too.

But, on same time, they can probably spend few months per year in regions with different gravity without any meaningful degrade in body functions.

For non humans. It depends, which creature it is.
If its aquatic creature like dolphin or fish, they will probably not notice change of gravity.
If its avian creature able to fly - probably it will be unable to fly properly at higher gravity.
If its non biped creature 4 or even 6 legs - it will probably survive higher gravity easier, that biped

Comment: Good answer thanks, interesting thought about certain humans suiting G levels better and about how creatures would fair.